# Fastest way to add a filter to many reports

Tags: reporting, filters, reports-folder

I've been tasked with adding a filter to literally hundreds of reports in Salesforce. As you can imagine, this is a very cumbersome task.

Currently I am simply clicking into each report and manually adding the filter. This could take HOURS. There has to be a better way.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Give the API a shot: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_list_resource.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have Premier Support, you can contact them and have them add this filter for you. If you have a consultant that knows decent programming, hand the job off to them, it probably shouldn't take more than an hour or two to download the reports, apply some kind of script to update many files at once, then upload the results back.

Realistically, if this is just a one-off procedure, it's probably better to pay to have it done. If you must do it yourself, it's a pretty simple procedure. Install [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode), and [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli), create a project, authenticate to your org, download the reports, use the Find In Files to find/replace in the new filter, and finally deploy the changes back to the server. It might still take an hour or two if you don't already have these tools, but someone who knows what they're doing could probably have this done in a few minutes.